# Errors in assets -- js and css -- when running a phoenix/elixir app with the default setting with brunch

Tags: jquery, css, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have a lot of "Uncaught ReferenceError:" and "jquery.waypoints.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property" kinds of errors in my phoenix/elixir app. This is because of the wrong order in which the js fileds are concatendated or loaded and namespaces which brunch inserts I think. But all the setting are default and there's nothing about that in the documenation.

My js and css are untouched, as well as brunch-config.js. I'm using bootstrap and jquery and my own scripts and css files. How can I set them up correctly? Should I put my jquery script and bootstrap into /vendor?

Here's my brunch-config.js

```
exports.config = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
        "js/vendor.js": /^(web\/static\/vendor)|(deps)/
      },
    },

    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: {
        "css/app.css"
        templates: {
          joinTo: "js/app.js"
        }
      }
    },

    conventions: {
      assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
    },

    paths: {
      watched: [
        "web/static",
        "test/static"
      ],

      public: "priv/static"
    },

    plugins: {
      babel: {
        ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
      }
    },

    modules: {
      autoRequire: {
        "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
      }
    },

    npm: {
      enabled: true,
      whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html"]
    }
  }
};
```

And my app.js

```
import "phoenix_html"
import "jquery"
import "bootstrap"
```

Comment: Did you try using the `order` array to manually specify the order, like the commented out code in the default generated `brunch-config.js` includes? See https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/f2e02d97ef79f825f6bbbdc2d7b69a1d005bff90/installer/templates/static/brunch/brunch-config.js#L14-L20

Comment: @Dogbert, it's not only the issue caused by order, it's also import or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

If you want to change the order the files are concatenated, you can do this inside your `brunch-config.js`:

```
exports.config = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
      order: {
        before: [
          "web/static/vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
          "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can do the same for CSS:

```
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: "css/app.css",
  order: {
    after: ["web/static/css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
  }
}
```

You can read the [Brunch docs](http://brunch.io/#documentation) for more info.

Note that if you go with this approach, you'll have to import the module inside your `app.js` file. For JQuery, assuming you installed it using npm, this should be `import $ from "jquery"`.

**Option 2:**

You can also place the files you want inside `/priv/static/js` and `priv/static/css` and then load them from inside your html (such as your layout file) like this:

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/myscript.js") %>"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/mystyles.css") %>">
```

I've had to do that a few times, such as when the library didn't expose itself as a module.

Comment: for the 2nd option, what should I put into `brunch-config.js`?

Comment: Nothing. Brunch is responsible for concatenating and minifying the JS and CSS you specify. The second option in my post bypasses Brunch completely. You can think of it as the "I'm going to handle these files manually myself" option.